# pusher issue on connection wrong cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pusher

This is the issue I am getting:

> application-169dad56b7bb7d53e3aaeaf87e8fc05c.js:156 Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4001,"message":"App key 2395af13c928012b447b not in this cluster. Did you forget to specify the cluster?"}}}

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you haven't specified the Pusher cluster to connect to, or specified one that is not the same as the one your app was configured to use in Pusher's Dashboard.

Specify the cluster to connect to [as described here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#initialization). The cluster your app is configured to use is shown at the bottom left of your app's page in [the dashboard](https://dashboard.pusher.com).